# Windows xp hangs with dim splash screen on setup's first boot

Tags: windows, windows-xp, boot, setup

I'm Installing windows xp in my Desktop,

and after first setup boot (which is comes next to "formatting disk", "copying files"),
the windows xp splash screen hangs and its very Dim.

I had never face this issue before, the ISO is same and even i've tried it with CD and USB as well with no luck.

I've following system configuration,

```
Intel Core 2 Duo Processor
1 GB + 2 GB RAM
160 GB HDD
```

Before Formatting i was using ubuntu with no problem at all. But after formatting HDD and during setup's first boot i'm facing this problem ... please help.

Comment: What is the source of the XP install disk?  Was this a retail XP package you purchased at some time or an iso you downloaded?

Comment: I'd Downloaded it once.

Comment: If you got it from Digital River this probably isn't an issue, but legit XP isos haven't been available for a very long time.  If you downloaded it in probably the last five years or so, I would question whether it is good.  Have you used it before with success?  If you are getting to the XP splash screen, I'm guessing that the issue isn't a problem with the MBR, which is not unusual after uninstalling Linux.

Comment: Yes.. I was using it without any hitch..

Comment: If word gets out, people will be beating a path to your door for a copy.  You may possess the only copy still in existence.  The black market opportunities are unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

New hardware sometimes need drivers, that didn't exist when Windows XP was published. - Very often there is no Windows support for the SATA-interface. DOS is running ok, but the system hangs or BSOD's when Windows is starting. - I have used this "work'a'round" several times:

Enter the BIOS and find the settings for the harddrive.
Look for something like SATA or IDE settings. If it is set to SATA (SCSI) or AHCI you must change it to IDE or Compatibility mode.
Then reboot the PC. You don't have to restart the Windows installation. It should resume automatically. Just make sure, the install CD is loaded.

If this works out, you can find a driver, that fits your specific SATA-interface/chipset. - Usually the manufacturer of the mainboard has these drivers for download. - When the driver is correctly installed, you can restore the BIOS-settings, in order to take full advantage of the SATA drive.